# Inject a service in a custom validator in Angular2

Tags: validation, typescript, angular

I try to use a service in a custom validator to check if a username already exists.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {
    Control,
    ControlGroup,
    FormBuilder
} from "angular2/common";
import {CharacterService} from "./character-service";

@Component({
    selector: 'register-character-form',
    template: `
        <h2 class="ui header">A new adventurer is coming...</h2>
        <form (ngSubmit)="register()" [ngFormModel]="characterForm" class="ui form">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Nom</label>
                <input ngControl="name">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="ui button">Enter in the adventure</button>
        </form>
    `,
    providers: [CharacterService]
})
export class RegisterCharacterFormCmp {
    characterForm: ControlGroup;
    name: Control;

    constructor(private _characterService: CharacterService, fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.name = fb.control('', this.characterNameValidator);

        this.characterForm = fb.group({
            name: this.name
        });
    }

    register(): void {
        //TODO: To implement
    }

    // Not works, this binds the control
    characterNameValidator(control: Control) {
        return this._characterService.isCharacterNameAlreadyExists(control.value) ? {nameCharacterAlreadyExistsError: true} : null;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. In the characterNameValidator, 'this' references the control and not my class. The service is undefined. How can I use my service in the validator ?

More globally, how can I pass arguments in a custom validator ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to control what `this` means in your validation. You can do so with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.name = fb.control('', this.characterNameValidator.bind(this));
```

Everything else should work as expected then.

Comment: you could also use an arrow function to keep this pointing to the right object.

Comment: @SnareChops - Can you please link where this is `bind` is documented? I can't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: @toskv: Can you please provide an example.

Comment: @self. Bind is a native javascript feature. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @self. I added an answer using the arrow function.

Comment: @SnareChops Thanks. I was searching for `bind` in Angular's source code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an arrow function to keep the context the same.

```
this.name = fb.control('', (control: Control) => this.characterNameValidator(control));
```

Comment: What about the validation parameters? The form will pass `control` to the arrow function, which is ignored, and then the `characterNameValidator` will never receive the parameter. If added in the argument list of the arrow function and then passed to the validator, then that would solve that issue, however what does this extra step actually help with compared to passing the validator as a bound function reference?

Comment: I added the parameters. Also since the characterNameValidator method returns something you can just do away with the block inside the arrow function.