# form's custom "Multi-Parameter" validator does not always fire

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have an Angular2.0.0-beta.9 and Typescript 1.7 app.  In this app I am creating a custom validator that uses more than one supplied parameter to determine if a control is valid.

I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461369/1854382) as inspiration

Here is the constructor of the class for my form:

```
constructor(fBuilder: FormBuilder) {

// initialize shift custom validators
this._sVal = new ShiftValidator; // a custom validator class I import

// build form controls
this.shiftForm = fBuilder.group({
    'TradeDate': ['2016-03-23', Validators.required],
    // other fields removed for brevity
    'SupervisorRankID': [0, (c: Control) => this._sVal.valSelectOptional(c, this.requireSupervisor())]
  });
}
```

Here is the validator class:

```
export class ShiftValidator {

// other validations removed for brevity
valSelectOptional(c: Control, required: boolean): { [s: string]: boolean } {
    if (Number(c.value) < 1 && required) {
        return { 'invalidSelection': true };
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the method / function I use to return the boolean value for the validator's second parameter:

```
    requireSupervisor(): boolean {
    if (this.currentTrade === undefined) { return false; }
    \\ NOTE: currentTrade is a custom class / object that is imported into this module
    if (this.currentTrade !== undefined) {
        return this.currentTrade.SupervisorApproval;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### The Problem

This validator is only "firing" when the booelan value I pass is changed to true.  When I change the value of requireSupervisor to be false, the validator does not trigger.

### Question

Can someone help me figure out why the validator does not trigger every time the value of its parameters change?

### EDIT 1:

I tried gunter's approach by adding a (ngModelChange)='requireSupervisor' to the check box and changing the **requireSupervisor** function to include a updateValueAndValidate on the whole control group:

```
    requireSupervisor(): boolean {
    if (this.currentTrade === undefined) {
        this.validateSupervisor();
        return false;
    }

    if (this.currentTrade !== undefined) {
        this.validateSupervisor();
        return this.currentTrade.SupervisorApproval;
    } else {
        this.validateSupervisor();
        return false;
    }
}

validateSupervisor(): void {
    if (this.shiftForm !== undefined) {
        this.shiftForm.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
}
```

If I change the above validateSupervisor function to the following I get a maximum call stack exceeded error:

```
validateSupervisor(): void {
    if (this.shiftForm !== undefined) {
        this.shiftForm.controls['SupervisorRankID'].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM**:
The validator logic works, the problem is the validator logic is only triggered when the checkbox is clicked/selected.  When you uncheck/deselect the check box the validator is not triggered.

Can someone help me figure out why the uncheck action of the check box does not fire the validator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the only option is:

```
control.updateValueAndValidity()
```

though its trigger should be added carefully to avoid undesired change detection.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AKHMZiWPt2cjq3OP5hnx?p=preview)

In this example switching `required` works fine, but if you try to do it directly from template `required!=required` it will fail.

Comment: thanks kemsky, your plunker put the final pieces together for me.  Don't spend all your rep on candy, or maybe you should.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is the expected behavior of a `ControlGroup Validator`, validation is fired for the altered controls only.

But you can manipulate this behavior using `updateValueAndValidity` as suggested by Gunter and kemsky, It just needs a little fine tuning

```
(<Control>this.shiftForm.controls['SupervisorRankID'])
   .updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf: true, emitEvent: true})

 // do this whenever requirement changes
```

**Note:**  don't put this inside `requireSupervisor()` or `validateSupervisor()`, because that will cause recursion.

> - If `onlySelf` is `true`, this change will only affect the validation of this `Control`  and not its parent component.
> - If `emitEvent` is `true`, this change will cause a `valueChanges` event on the `Control` to be emitted.
> - Both of these options default to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

This should invoke validation:

```
this.shiftForm.controls['SupervisorRankID'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

might need a cast

```
(<Control>this.shiftForm.controls['SupervisorRankID'])
    .updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: thanks gunter, I have been trying to make this work for a while, but it does not work for me.  I tied the ngModelChange event of the check box to a function in my forms view model and when I use your code I get a maximum call stack size exceeded error.

Comment: that's probably because of recursion caused by `updateValueAndValidity()` triggering `validateSupervisor()` and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to set the emitEvent on false for that formControl updateValueAndValidity method.

**for example something like this**:

```
this.shiftForm.controls['SupervisorRankID'].updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent : false});
```

**from Angular docs**:

> If emitEvent is true, this change will cause a valueChanges event on
>   the FormControl to be emitted. This defaults to true (as it falls
>   through to updateValueAndValidity).

Also you have the possibility to onlySelf to false (is true by default) like this:

```
this.shiftForm.controls['SupervisorRankID'].updateValueAndValidity({onlySelf : true});
```

from Angular docs:

> If onlySelf is true, this change will only affect the validation of
>   this FormControl and not its parent component. This defaults to false.

I was having a similar problem with a tricky and big form. emitEvent saves me.

Hope it helps you.

Learn more about formControls here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

Comment: I was trying to answer another question :P
Sorry, too many open tabs. My bad.